# Why does stored function returns empty result in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to write a stored function in the MongoDB server. When I try the following function

```js
db.collection.find({$where: function() { return (Number(this.zip) == (10018));}});
```

This works fine. But When I save this using

```js
db.system.js.save({_id: "zip", value: function() { return (Number(this.zip) == (10018));}});
```

And call it in following way

```js
db.collection.find({$where: "zip()"});
```

It returns an empty result. Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of JS context rules. `this` in the function is not the same as `this` in the caller's scope. Try:

```
db.collection.find({$where: "zip.call(this)"});
```

[More information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).